# Formatted excel attachment in UNIX sendmail

Tags: unix

Is it possible to send an excel attachment having some rows in red colored highlighted?

Currently I am using below coding format(similar) for sending plan excel attachment:

```
(
 echo "From: $MAILFROM"
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"-$MAILPART\""
 echo "---$MAILPART"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo "---$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 uuencode -m $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 echo "---$MAILPART--"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```

Is there any way to add something in above code to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the color of the cells you have in the excel file you may use the same script to send a file of any type with a small change to the script:

```
(
 echo "From: $MAILFROM"
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"-$MAILPART\""
 echo "---$MAILPART"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo "---$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 uuencode -m $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 echo "---$MAILPART--"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```